# Fallback content on an "unnamed" slot is never displayed

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, html5-template

I'm trying to figure out how web components are working and can't fully understand rules around fallback content in slots:

I have a web-component like:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <slot name="content">
    <span>fallback</span>
  </slot>
  <slot>
    <span>fallback on an anonymus slot</span>
  </slot>
  <section>...and more content form shadow DOM</section>
`;

class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement{
  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

window.customElements.define('some-component', SomeComponent);
```

and if I put this component on a page like

```
<some-component>
  <span slot="content">named slot content</span>
</some-component>
```

I never see a "fallback" content for unnamed slot:

[image]

but it does present in the shadow DOM:

[image]

I don't use any pollyfills and rely on current Chrome web-components support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the expected behavior.
Actually the fallback sould not be display because some elements are caught and revealed by the unnamed `<slot>` element: the (invisible `space` and `CRLF`) text elements before the `<span>` and after the `</span>` tags.

If you remove them:

```
<some-component><span slot="content">named slot content</span></some-component>
```

...then you will see the fallback text!

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <slot name="content">
    <span>fallback</span>
  </slot>
  <slot>
    <span>fallback on an anonymus slot</span>
  </slot>
  <section>...and more content form shadow DOM</section>
`;

class SomeComponent extends HTMLElement{
  constructor() {
    super();

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

window.customElements.define('some-component', SomeComponent);
```

```html
<some-component><span slot="content">named slot content</span></some-component>
```